# cant receive data from a php file

Tags: android

i am trying to post and receive data from a php file.
but i am not able to do it.
this is my code for posting and receiving data into a php file

```
            public void submit(){

    String result = null; 
    InputStream is = null; 
    StringBuilder sb=null; 

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registerno",registerno));
             try{ 
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://serveraddress/a.php"); 
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
    is = entity.getContent(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString()); 
    } //convert response to string

    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),80); 
    sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n"); 
    String line="0"; 
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    { 
        sb.append(line + "\n"); } 
    is.close(); 
    result=sb.toString(); 
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
```

and this is my php file
a.php

```
 <?php
 $reg=$_POST['registerno'];
 print(json_encode($reg));
 ?>
```

i am getting output as

```
      "android.widget.EditText@45f6567d8"
```

can anyone help me out for this

Comment: the problem is you are printing the class of your editText, you should use `result.getText().toString()` instead of `result.toString`

Answer (score 1):

use **toString()** when getting value from `EditText` something like : `getText().toString();`